# AS3: How to scale down multiple external html images in TextArea object's htmlText?

Tags: html, css, image, actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to AS3, and last touched Flash when it was with Macromedia, version 4.

I'm building a flashapp to display images via html data.
The data is populated in a `TextArea` object via `htmlText` property.
The `TextArea` container has a fixed width and height;

In the html data, I have multiple `<img>` tags referencing external images.
However, the problem arise when the image referenced is larger than the `TextArea` dimensions.

```
import fl.controls.TextArea;

var box:*;

box = TextArea();
box.htmlText = "External HTML Data with multiple <img src='elsewhere.jpg'> tags"
```

The images within the external data does not have any `id` attributes in it.

I've tried css styling with the styleSheet property, but flash only supports a subset of CSS1 specs.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html

So css `max-width` is nowhere to be found.

The closest possible solution I've read about, uses `getImageReference` method
[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getImageReference()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getImageReference%28%29)
from TextField object.

This method requires the image in the image to be first loaded, then be called by `getImageReference` via `id` attribute to get a `DisplayObject` which then can be manipulated.

From here, it seems that I would need to get a `string.match` method on the external data to match and insert different `id` attribute for each `<img>` tag. Then, after loading, has to be looped through to manually calculate each of the image size, then set their scaling properties to keep aspect ratio.

This solution seems complicated, and it might not actually work.

I would like to ask if anyone has a better simpler solution that I might have missed while digging through the documentation.

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may find a solution, and it sounds like you've done a good job digging for yourself so I don't doubt if someone has an answer they'll try to help you, but depending on what you're trying to achieve this might just not be a good way to use AS3.  The HTML and CSS support is lacking to say the least, and expecting it to do anything above the minimum is asking too much (unfortunately they didn't do anything crafty like the WebView in Android or iOS with a webkit implementation, it seems they rolled their own, or have a very limited implementation)

Comment: @shaunhusain thanks. I've got my limitations, unfortunately, hence the choice. I feel like I'm facing IE6 all over again.